# changing the image source using jquery and Kurento

Tags: javascript, jquery, kurento

I use Kurento-magic-mirror and everytime i would change image, i am forced to change the name of the picture mario-Wings.png.

Here is the code shown

```js
function getopts(args, opts)
{
  var result = opts.default || {};
  args.replace(
      new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
      function($0, $1, $2, $3) { result[$1] = decodeURI($3); });
 
  return result;
};
 
var args = getopts(location.search,
{
  default:
  {
    ws_uri: 'ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/kurento',
    hat_uri: 'http://' + location.host + '/img/mario-wings.png',
    ice_servers: undefined
  }
});
```

suppose we have several images at the interface
Now, I would like to change the image by making a click.

I started to create a function but this function is not automatic by against this changes the picture at startup

```js
function changeImage(nom){
  

 console.log(" Avant Changement de l'image ");
 args = getopts(location.search,
 {
    default:{
      ws_uri: 'ws://' + location.hostname + ':8888/kurento',
                hat_uri: 'http://' + location.host + '/img/test5.jpg',
      ice_servers: undefined 
     } 
        });

 $("#test5").attr('src', 'img/test5.jpg');
 console.log("Après Changement de l'image ");
   
}
```

How to solve this problem ???

Help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the variable, but not doing anything with it. Following the [lead](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/blob/fe6e92eb22e03588d9b90a7f4054f9c0e1ae662b/kurento-magic-mirror/js/index.js#L158) of the tutorial, this is what you need to do

```
function changeImage(hatUri, offsetXPercent, offsetYPercent, widthPercent, heightPercent) {
   filter.setOverlayedImage(hatUri, offsetXPercent, offsetYPercent, widthPercent, heightPercent,
      function(error) {
         if (error) return onError(error);
         console.log("Set overlay image");
      });
}
```

I strongly recommend that you study the examples, and understand each line of code. If you change a value in the client, but don't instruct the media server to change the value too, it's useless.